# jQuery GET External Rest Service

Tags: jquery, rest

I'm invoking "GET" method for local restful services from jQuery with success. But when I try an external service, I do not make it work.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$.ajax({ 
type: "GET", 
dataType: "text/xml", 
url: "http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx/GetGeoIP?IPAddress=158.42.38.1", 
success: function(data){ 
alert("Working"); 
}, 
error:function(res){ 
alert("Not working "); 
} 
}); 
</script>
```

Does anybody see where is the error?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check your console, probably SOP

Comment: same origin police blocks you ,check whether the service provider support jsonp